# When i crop the photos, they end up hiding the captions within the thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

When i crop the photos, they end up hiding the captions within the thumbnail. What can i do to make the captions content appear and also make the images be of the same height.

[image]
I want to achieve something like this
![][2]

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var heights = $(".thumnbnail").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $(".thumnbnail").height(maxHeight);
});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
 height: 200px;
 width: 300px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail img {
 height: auto;
 width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://ksassets.timeincuk.net/wp/uploads/sites/55/2017/11/GettyImages-873359588-920x584.jpg" alt="osooabina"  class="img-responsive image thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,.
                </div>                
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/22/5e/80/225e80ea57b247c188ac160ed34fe3cf--ariana-grande-tattoos-ariana-grande-no-makeup.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="caption">
                  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,.
                </div>
            </div>  
        </a>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://gazettereview.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Eminem-Featured-image.jpg" alt="osooabina"  class="img-responsive image thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,.
                </div>
            </div>
        </a> 
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="https://www.biography.com/.image/t_share/MTQ3MzM3MTcxNjA5NTkzNjQ3/ariana_grande_photo_jon_kopaloff_getty_images_465687098.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="caption">
                  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,.
                </div>                
            </div>  
        </a>  
    </div>              
</div>
```

How can i make this code look like the one in the picture above.

Comment: I can't see a difference between the images.

Comment: You should probably start by picking a more unique class for determining height.  `thumbnail` is applied both to your `<div>` and `<img>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem you're having is related to your repeated use of `.thumbnail`.  You're applying it to the `<div>` and to the `<img>` and your jQuery script tries to apply `maxHeight` to both.

If we revise your code to look like this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var heights = $(".thumbnail").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $(".thumbnail").height(maxHeight);
});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.thumbnail img {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://ksassets.timeincuk.net/wp/uploads/sites/55/2017/11/GettyImages-873359588-920x584.jpg" alt="osooabina"  class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,.</div>                
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>    
    
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/22/5e/80/225e80ea57b247c188ac160ed34fe3cf--ariana-grande-tattoos-ariana-grande-no-makeup.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,.</div>
        </div>  
      </a>
    </div>    

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://gazettereview.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Eminem-Featured-image.jpg" alt="osooabina"  class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,.</div>
        </div>
      </a> 
    </div>  

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://www.biography.com/.image/t_share/MTQ3MzM3MTcxNjA5NTkzNjQ3/ariana_grande_photo_jon_kopaloff_getty_images_465687098.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
          <div class="caption">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,.</div>
        </div>
      </a> 
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll get something more akin to your source image.  Note that this doesn't address the concern of the actual images being the same dimensions; it merely ensures that your `.thumbnail` wrappers are all the same height.

I would also recommend you turn this into a function that is run both when the page loads and in the event of a window resize event.